# FFMPEG TS Null packet transmission

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to transmit TS packets using Ethernet. I am using C++ and ffmpeg libraries. At the moment I can send a hevc encoded ts stream via Ethernet successfully. But the output data rate varies. I want to maintain a constant(approximately) data rate..

I am using "av_interleaved_write_frame()" to transmit the TS packets.

I know this can be achieved using NULL packet transmission. Can anyone tell me how to do this using ffmpeg?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called Constant BitRate: you should set minrate, maxrate and bitrate to the same value to get it.

cf similar questions for more detailed examples:

- https://superuser.com/a/314355/329216
- [How to force Constant Bit Rate using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10908796/3194340)

And interesting external links:

- https://support.octoshape.com/entries/25126002-Encoding-best-practices-using-ffmpeg